# Подключение библиотеки jQuery к файлу .js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Просматривал варианты ответов как на русскоязычной, так и на англ. версии сообщества. Но не нашел оптимальный(то есть я пробовал, но не получилось) путь к подключению. Прошу помочь с этим вопросом.

Делал несколькими способами, из адекватных:

в **head** сразу прописывал пути к скачанной либе и своему файлу .js, где хочу использовать jQuery.

```
<script src="JS/jQuerySrc/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="JS/app.js"></script>
```

Не получилось.

Потом динамически в файле .js делал тег **script**, устанавливал атрибут **src** с путем к нужному файлу и добавлял в **head**.

Тоже не получилось.

Comment: указывайте полный путь к файлам от корня начиная с `/`, иначе в каком нибудь `site.ru/catalog` у вас скрипты не подключатся. и уберите подключение скриптов в конец страницы, чтобы не тормозили загрузку DOM. подключайте так же минифицированную версию. Откройте в браузере в инструментах вкладку Сеть и посмотрите, что там в ответ на запрос скрипта приходит. надо полагать увидите 404.

Comment: @teran, понял про путь, расположение скриптов и версию либы. Спасибо. Но в данной ситуации(учебный проект), не использование абсолютного пути к файлу, полной версии либы не влияет на то, что я не могу использовать jQuery в своем .js файле. Прошу помочь с этим. При нажатии F12 и переходе в пункт Console никаких ошибок нет, как и в пункте Сети 404.

Comment: если все подключается, дак может вы используете его не так как надо? приведите ваш код, чего там не работает то?

Comment: @teran по невнимательности опечатался в названии подключаемого файла. Час искал что не так. Спасибо за отклик.